# ASP.NET Core MVC - Why does Ajax JSON request return 400 on POST instead of 403

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application. If I'm doing a AJAX POST with `dataType: "json"`, and I return a `Forbid()` then I always get a `400 Bad Request` instead of returning `403 Forbidden`. But in case of a GET-Request the `403 Forbidden` is returned

Following Example - I'm using .NET Core 6 with this startup-script:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/");
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMiddleware<SerilogMiddleware>();
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
        .RequireAuthorization();
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        return Forbid();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] //just for demo to keep it simple
    public ActionResult Post()
    {
        return Forbid();

    }
}
```

Ajax-Requests:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Home/Get",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status);
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/Post",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status);
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

The GET-Request returns a `403 Forbidden`, the POST-Request returns a `400 Bad Request`.

[image]

Why isn't the POST-Request also returning an `403 Forbidden`? If I don't set the `dataType` and the `contentType`, then the POST-Request also returns a `403 Forbidden`.

Especially I also want to handle `403 Forbidden` and `401 Unauthorized` on JSON-Ajax calls. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I don't set the dataType and the contentType, then the POST-Request also returns a 403 Forbidden.

That's the key to figuring out what's going on. You are setting content type to application/json, but you are sending an empty body. Empty bodies are not valid JSON

In ASP.NET the content negotiation (the bit that deserializes your inputs. Runs before the controller body. If it fails, it will 400 or 405 depending on the source of the failure.

Comment: The issue was not the missing body. It looks like that `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` causes the issue. The AntiForgeryToken is ignored, but if you return anything else than `return Ok();` then the response is always `400 Bad Request`. After adding the CSRF to the header and removing the `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` it returns the correct status code.

Comment: Interesting! I learned something